# Android: Are buttons heavier than textviews as controls (or vice-versa)?

Tags: android, performance, button, memory-management, textview

My app features a special view that can contain hundreds of textviews and buttons (but a few appear on screen thanks to a scrollview). It has not troubles for this but it is slow at creation time when adding textviews and buttons if they are very numberous.
I would like to know whether textviews and button are the same from a performance point of view, or instead one is heavier than the other in terms of memory, speed, and so on, because I have also the possibility to use just only textviews or only buttons.

Comment: Hundreds of views on screen at once?!

Comment: Kind of hard without knowing your layout but you should definitely avoid hundreds of views being loaded into memory at one time. Consider using a customized ListView so that it can handle the memory better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this link will provide full answer to your question: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/Button.java

In short words: Button is exactly same as TextView. It just use another style.

edit: And yes, you better think about another way of handling you feature. Hundreds of view is bad for performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of items on the screen then use a listView
Items it loaded dynamically